# Should we bind parameters inside or outside of a SQLite transaction?

Tags: sqlite, transactions

I am interested in using transactions for performance.

*This is the process I'm currently doing:*

```
* ~~~BEGIN TRANSACTION~~~
* Instance a command object and set the command text.
* Prepare command text so parameters can be added.
* In a loop, I set the values of said parameters and execute the command.
* ~~~COMMIT~~~
```

I am doing this because, as far as I understand, when you prepare a statement, you ARE communicating with the SQLite engine, so maybe encompassing that in the transaction helps in some way???  (I'm just speculating.)

.

**Question:** *Should I change it to the following process?*

```
* Instance a command object and set the command text.
* Prepare command text so parameters can be added.
* ~~~BEGIN TRANSACTION~~~
* In a loop, I set the values of said parameters and execute the command.
* ~~~COMMIT~~~
```

I am asking about this because, maybe, making the transaction contain ONLY series of homogenous commands seems like it might be better???  (Again, I have no idea; I'm just speculating.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no advantage to preparing statements inside `BEGIN` (with caveat below).

There is a small advantage to preparing the statements outside the `BEGIN` since the transaction will be slightly smaller in time (with second caveat below), thereby permitting more concurrency.

In either case, be sure to reset the statement before reusing it, and finalize the statement before closing the database.

Caveat 1: if the database schema changes, the statement will need to be re-prepared. If you use the recommended `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` then SQLite will do this for you. You can avoid schema changes by preparing inside a transaction, but note that you will need to use `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` to be sure the database is locked.

Caveat 2: Since you use `BEGIN` rather than `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` the database lock is not actually taken until the first statement of the transaction is stepped. So, there isn't really a concurrency advantage unless you are using `BEGIN IMMEDIATE`.

There are other advantages to preparing statements outside transactions, e.g., you can use them in multiple transactions without preparing multiple times. However, the logic to maintain their lifetimes becomes more complex/disbursed.